# UIPickerView reloadAllComponents doesn't get called

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipickerview

I have 2 table cells, based on what i have selected in my first cell, i have to refresh the second cell, when i click the second cell a container view with a picker is changed from hidden to unhidden state.

When I press the cell I have a method which gets called where after i get the new data I reload my picker, but that line of code doesn't get called, my picker isn't refreshed:

```
-(void)reloadData:(NSUInteger) path{
    //NSUInteger path = (NSUInteger)self.parentVC.pozOras;
    NSString *parcareFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Parcare"
                                                            ofType:@"plist"];
    self.fisier = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:parcareFile];
    ////Log(@"reloadData:%@",self.fisier);
    NSDictionary *infoOras = [self.fisier objectAtIndex:path];
   // NSLog(@"reloadData:%@",infoOras);
    NSLog(@"reloadData:%d",(NSInteger)path);

    NSArray *zones = [infoOras valueForKey:@"Zone"];

    self.zone = [zones valueForKey:@"name"];
    NSLog(@"reloadData:%@",self.zone);
    self.price = [zones valueForKey:@"price"];
    NSLog(@"reloadData:%@",self.price);
    self.time = [zones valueForKey:@"durationminutes"];
    NSLog(@"reloadData:%@",self.time);

    [self.listaCuZone reloadAllComponents];



}
```

All the data from the Output of NSLog is what is should be in the picker.
I have the property of the UIPickerView in the header file, everything seems to be in place. I really don't know why it doesn't get called.

```
   @interface PickerZone : UIViewController<UIPickerViewDataSource,UIPickerViewDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, assign) FirstViewController *parentVC;
@property NSInteger zona;
@property NSUInteger path;
@property NSMutableArray *fisier;
@property NSMutableArray *zone, *price, *time;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIPickerView *listaCuZone;




- (IBAction)doneButton:(id)sender;
- (void)reloadData:(NSUInteger)path;
@end
```

Here is where i call the method from:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    if(indexPath.section == 0){
        [self.listaZone viewForBaselineLayout].hidden = YES;
        [self.listaOrase viewForBaselineLayout].hidden = NO;
    }
    else
    {
        PickerZone *pickerZone = [[PickerZone alloc]init];
        [pickerZone reloadData:(NSUInteger)self.pozOras];
        [pickerZone.listaCuZone reloadAllComponents];
        [self.listaOrase viewForBaselineLayout].hidden = YES;
        [self.listaZone viewForBaselineLayout].hidden = NO;
    }
}
```

As you can see, i also try to reload the components here.
I have the delegate and the datasource also linked to the vc.

If i should post some more code please let me know, i really want to fix this.

Here is a screenshot of the storyboard: https://www.dropbox.com/s/4nkpz55zlcffh9w/Screenshot%202014-02-16%2019.31.24.png

Comment: you should first add the picker as a subview then reload data.

Comment: I dont realy understood your problem, but I think your mistake can be in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method, cuz in else statement you are create PickerZone instance that doesn't showed anywhere, and actualy will be released when method will end.

Comment: I have a container view, in which i have a button and the picker. When i press the tableview th container becomes visible and i can make a selection in the picker. the data in the picker should reload based on what i have in the first tableviewcell. i am going to post a picture of my storyboard